# I can not addObject to NSMutableArray initializedWith 5 string objects

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apranax Forte",
                                                         @"Actified",
                                                         @"Zostex 125 MG",
                                                         @"Zoprotec 30 MG",
                                                         @"Arveles 25 MG"];

[array insertObject:@"Ahmet" atIndex:[array count] + 1]; // Neither work
[array addObject:@"Ahmet"]
```

I want to append the Ahmet string to the NSMutableArray array object ... Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `insertObject: atIndex:[array count]+1` will never work. the last element is at index `[array count]-1`. the largest index you can insert into is `[array count]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not instaniating a mutable array:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apranax Forte",
                                        @"Actified",
                                        @"Zostex 125 MG",
                                        @"Zoprotec 30 MG",
                                        @"Arveles 25 MG",
                                        nil];
```

Also don't forget to terminate the collection of objects with nil.

Comment: Sometimes focusing on only one thing much more than normal prevents seeing big picture.. thnx

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you terminate your array with "nil"

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apranax Forte",     @"Actified",@"Zostex 125 MG",@"Zoprotec 30 MG",@"Arveles 25 MG", nil];
```

Comment: tHANKs to everyone .. ı do not know if stackoverflow exists !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `[NSArray alloc]` to `[NSMutableArray alloc]`

Comment: tHANKs to everyone .. ı do not know if stackoverflow exists !!